# send json data via REST request on talend

Tags: json, rest, elasticsearch, talend

I want to send data to my elasticsearch  database.
for that I recover my data from an oracle database I transform them into json and send them via a REST request on talend

I use elasticsearch versions 7.0.1 and talend 7.1.1

data send :

```
{"name": "Fabrice", "site": "Paris", "department": "North West"}
```

method put  in this url : "http://localhost:9200/my_index"

i have this error :

```
Exception in component tRESTClient_1 (myProject)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not passing an ID in the url, then you need to use the "**POST**" method.

I got a similar error when I tried running the query you posted in Kibana.

You can read more here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html

PS: I don't know how Talend plays into things, but I'm assuming you are running it locally otherwise I would have expected a different error about not being able to reach "localhost".

Comment: thanks for your answer i did post and now i have another different error

Exception in component tRESTClient_1 (myproject)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request

Comment: Do you have "_doc"? included? Here's a full curl that works for me. :
```curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_doc" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"name": "Fabrice", "site": "Paris", "department": "North West"}'```

Comment: the request with curl work well , {"_index":"my_index","_type":"_doc","_id":"cxKpxGoBohmIlODzkrLA","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"_seq_no":0,"_primary_term":5}